# How to get duration from HTML5 Multiple video?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have multiple video tags in single screen with absolute position and want to get that longer video from multiple and when longer video ends want to execute code.

```
<div id="#p0">
<div style="width:1320px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:600px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:1321px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:1000px;height:600px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px;z-index:5;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="3.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
</div>
```

and i have tried below code but getting NaN when log duration

```
$('#p0 div video').each(function() {                 
            console.log($(this));
            alert($(this).duration);console.log("dur "+$(this).duration);
               if (longestVid == "" || longestVid.duration < $(this).duration)
                  longestVid = this;
        });
```

How can i get duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to wait to get duration until the video's metadata has loaded (otherwise duration will report 'undefined').  Also, you probably need to request `$(this)[0].duration` instead of `$(this).duration`.

```
$('#p0 div video').each(function() { 
    var $el = $(this);
    console.log('pre-load, duration is', $el[0].duration);
    $el.one('loadedmetadata play', function () {
        console.log('loaded, duration is now', $el[0].duration);
    });
}
```